# How to add external jar file to gingerbread source code

Tags: android

I have gingerbread source code and i am customizing some native apps.
now I want to external jar file 'asmack.jar' in the native contact project.
I simply did this by

> project>properties>java build path>Libraries>Add external Jar.

But I am getting the error :

> package org.jivesoftware.smack does not exist

please help me, how to overcome this.
thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882167/creating-a-product-sdk-how-do-i-add-a-native-lib-so-and-a-jar-with-the-sdk-i

Answer (score 0):

Try do what I do:
create a folder in your project, call it jars.
then, copy your jars to the folder.
Then, right-click on the jar you want to add, choose: Build Path -> Add To Build Path.
And thats it.
I hope I helped :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried this already.. I am adding the jar file to gingerbread source code.