# Why do I get java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError when I start the android app which uses tes two OCR engine

Tags: android, unsatisfiedlinkerror

This is the logcat report I get when I run the application

```
07-06 15:39:40.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6777): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-06 15:39:40.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6777): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
07-06 15:39:40.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6777):     at edu.sfsu.cs.orange.ocr.CaptureActivity.initOcrEngine(CaptureActivity.java:714)
07-06 15:39:40.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6777):     at edu.sfsu.cs.orange.ocr.CaptureActivity.onResume(CaptureActivity.java:371)
07-06 15:39:40.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6777):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1184)
07-06 15:39:40.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6777):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5082)
07-06 15:39:40.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6777):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2569)
07-06 15:39:40.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6777):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2607)
07-06 15:39:40.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6777):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2093)
07-06 15:39:40.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6777):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134)
07-06 15:39:40.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6777):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1199)
07-06 15:39:40.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6777):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-06 15:39:40.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6777):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-06 15:39:40.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6777):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4744)
07-06 15:39:40.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6777):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-06 15:39:40.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6777):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-06 15:39:40.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6777):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-06 15:39:40.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6777):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-06 15:39:40.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6777):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-06 15:39:40.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6777): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load lept: findLibrary returned null
07-06 15:39:40.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6777):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
07-06 15:39:40.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6777):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
07-06 15:39:40.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6777):     at com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.<clinit>(TessBaseAPI.java:44)
07-06 15:39:40.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6777):     ... 17 more
```

I'm trying to run an OCR application using the tess-two library which I downloaded. I opened this project in eclipse and added as a library to my project. But when I start the application it crashes giving me the above log. Do I need to compile the tess two library before running my application. If so, please help me on how I can compile it on a windows 8 computer.

Comment: `Couldn't load lept: findLibrary returned null` Any native libraries used in your project? Post your code!

Comment: I use tess-two OCR library. I think it's written in C.. So do I need to compile the library?

Comment: Yes. See http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#GetStarted

Comment: I read the tess-two git hub page https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two and they've mentioned that I need to compile the code using linux terminal! is it possible to compile it in windows!

Comment: It says "The build works on Linux, Mac OS X, and Windows 7". It's build by the NDK, which creates ARM executable code for Android. This has nothing to do with your platform

Comment: Oh ok! thanks for the reply! I'll build the library using the ndk and check! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the bottom of your Stack-Trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldnt load lept: findLibrary returned null
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
    [...]
```

In your code, you're using native libraries (e.g. libraries which are written in C/C++ and are interfaced with [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface)). The problem here is, that the  library-files can not be found by Android. Therefor, the `UnsatisfiedLinkError` is thrown.

The native *sources* of your application should be located in the `jni/`-subdirectory of your project. You'll also need a build-script to build your sources with the NDK cross-compiler. In your case, these files are [shipped with the library](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two#build).

In general, the compiled `.so`-files go into the `libs/`-folder of your project and can then be loaded by using the [`System.loadLibrary(String)`-method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#loadLibrary%28java.lang.String%29), often put in a static-initializer block:

```
System.loadLibrary("filename");
```

More information on library placement can be found here: [How do I import a native library (.so file) into Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8650472/717341)