# How to implement ooVoo library in android?

Tags: android, audio, videochat

I am trying to implement ooVoo library that provide's video, audio chat between user's, and I have downloaded the SDK from this [Link](https://developer.oovoo.com/dashboard) after registration.

I have read the documentation for ooVoo library but somehow i am not able to run even it's sample demo. So if anyone have implemented this library then please guide me how to do this ?

I have added **oovooSdk.jar** file to my project.

When I try to run this app first time I am getting following error in my logcat.

```
04-03 09:35:21.054: E/dalvikvm(1914): dlopen("/data/app-lib/com.ooVoo.oovoosample-1/liboovoo-sdk.so") failed: Cannot load library: soinfo_link_image(linker.cpp:1635): could not load library "libva.so" needed by "liboovoo-sdk.so"; caused by load_library(linker.cpp:745): library "libva.so" not found
04-03 09:35:21.054: D/AndroidRuntime(1914): Shutting down VM
04-03 09:35:21.054: W/dalvikvm(1914): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4ce9908)
04-03 09:35:21.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1914): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-03 09:35:21.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1914): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: soinfo_link_image(linker.cpp:1635): could not load library "libva.so" needed by "liboovoo-sdk.so"; caused by load_library(linker.cpp:745): library "libva.so" not found
04-03 09:35:21.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1914):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:371)
04-03 09:35:21.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1914):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
04-03 09:35:21.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1914):     at com.oovoo.core.ConferenceCore.<init>(ConferenceCore.java:289)
04-03 09:35:21.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1914):     at com.oovoo.core.ConferenceCore.instance(ConferenceCore.java:176)
04-03 09:35:21.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1914):     at com.ooVoo.oovoosample.ConferenceManager.<init>(ConferenceManager.java:103)
04-03 09:35:21.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1914):     at com.ooVoo.oovoosample.ConferenceManager.getInstance(ConferenceManager.java:94)
04-03 09:35:21.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1914):     at com.ooVoo.oovoosample.Main.MainActivity.initConferenceManager(MainActivity.java:104)
04-03 09:35:21.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1914):     at com.ooVoo.oovoosample.Main.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:58)
04-03 09:35:21.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1914):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
04-03 09:35:21.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1914):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
04-03 09:35:21.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1914):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
04-03 09:35:21.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1914):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-03 09:35:21.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1914):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-03 09:35:21.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1914):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-03 09:35:21.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1914):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-03 09:35:21.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1914):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-03 09:35:21.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1914):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
04-03 09:35:21.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1914):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-03 09:35:21.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1914):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-03 09:35:21.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1914):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-03 09:35:21.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1914):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-03 09:35:21.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1914):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: ooVoo Library, sounds nice, How do you get all these ideas ?

Comment: @Kedarnath, I just want to implement the same for my project, then i searched and i get this SDK and so many other's also, but this looks inerestings to me, so i thought to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

I know is an old question, but the ooVoo SDK uses native code and requires the JNI to interact with the FFI.  Depending on your IDE, these libs need placed in various locations.

The oovoosdk.jar is going out looking for these .so files and it is not finding them.  Get those libs linked correctly and it will work fine.

[Using Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650472/how-do-i-import-a-native-library-so-file-into-eclipse)

At the time of writing, with Android Studio, the files need to be placed in, `src/main/jniLibs` and do a "Gradle Sync" with project after placing them in.

Answer (score 0):

Just login to [ooVoo developers site](http://developer.oovoo.com/) ,

1. After loging-in go to dashboard
2. Click CREATE A NEW APP button - AppId will be generated
3. Click VIEW button and again click VIEW TOKEN and Again click ADD TOKEN - token will be generated
4. Place the **AppID** inside meta-data of Manifest file.
5. Also place your **TOKEN** inside meta-data of Manifest file. Please be careful while copying TOKEN. ***RUN IT ON A REAL TIME DEVICE.***
   THIS WORKED FOR ME. Hope this steps help you.

Comment: can u plse elaborate the step.. to implement the oovoo sdk in android... i am getting error..

Comment: @param , please tell me, did you download the sample project? and also explain me in which file are you getting error?

Comment: thanks for ur reply... i am getting error..java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ooVoo.oovoosample.ConferenceManager
E/AndroidRuntime(24653):    at com.ooVoo.oovoosample.Main.MainActivity.initConferenceManager(MainActivity.java:103)

Comment: @param I also found this error....and the strange thing about that...was...the same code (sample), giving the same error you told on one machine, and  working fine (without any error), on other machines

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you deployed all .so files to the device.

ooVoo SDK is provided for 2 platforms - x86 and armeabi v7a. armeabi implementation has only 1 .so file, x86 has 3.

Some android devices do not handle it correctly - they expect same files for both platforms. In order to solve it you can create empty files (with size 0) with the names libva-android.so and libva.so in arm folder - should help.

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem for me:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("oovoo-sdk");
    }
    ...
}
```