# How to add so library to android application

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have .so library and it's 'JNICall' class, which is an interface for it. They was wrote not by me. To be honest, I decompiled one apk to get them. So the question - It is possible to use them in my project, and how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to find proper documentation for your library otherwise it'll be difficult to integrate,

as for including the so file in your project follow this:

> [How do I import a native library (.so file) into Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650472/how-do-i-import-a-native-library-so-file-into-eclipse)

Comment: There is no documentation for libray, because I decompiled the apk file to get it) I have decompiled example which use it, so it is much easier to reengenere dependencies for it.