# How can I access .so file in apk at runtime?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'd like to access(read) my .so file built in NDK at runtime in order to 
check up on its hash value.

To do that, I used AAssetManager_open() function but always failed.

```
const char* filename = "/data/data/com.mycompany.app/lib/libmyndk.so"; // failed with this.

const char* filename = "assets/libmyndk.so"; // Also failed with this.

AAsset* asset = AAssetManager_open(mgr, (const char*) filename, AASSET_MODE_UNKNOWN);
```

Please let me know why it persist to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved out this issue. We don't need to use AssetManager for just simply accessing.

just use fopen() in NDK(c/c++ files).

for example,

```
void initNDK()
{
     const char* filename = "/data/data/com.company.app/lib/libmyndk.so";
     FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
     if(fp) 
         TRACE("Success");
     else
         TRACE("Failure");
}
```

Thank you All.

Answer (score 0):

you have load .so file during application start.

By

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("libpacman");
}
```

Than you can access file .

i hope this is help you.

Comment: Pretty good idea. but What can I do with this? Could you give an example to read the so file in binary mode or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
const char* filename = "libmyndk.so";
```

Comment: Yes, it fails. AAssetManager_open() returns NULL.

Comment: But strangely, the following statement also fails. const char* filename = "AndroidManifest.xml";

Answer (score 0):

Above all, I succeeded in reading/accessing some file in assets folder with AAssetManager_open().
But this AAssetManager_xxxx() functions seem to be only available to access files in assets folder.

What I want to do is to access my .so file built in NDK. Still looking for answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use native files you need to use android NDK.

This link will help you if you use Eclipce: [How do I import a native library (.so file) into Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650472/how-do-i-import-a-native-library-so-file-into-eclipse)

And this is for Android Studio: http://www.kylethielk.com/blog/include-native-so-library-in-apk-with-android-studio/

I hope it helps to resolve your problem.