# Null Pointer Exception in "Linphone" Library Android

Tags: android, eclipse, nullpointerexception, linphone

I have created an Android Application in that I want to make voice and video call using "Linphone" library.

I successfully download and setup the library project but when I run project get the below error in "LinphoneService.java" file.

I get error in this lines:

```
LinphoneCoreFactory.instance().setLogCollectionPath(
            getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath());
LinphoneCoreFactory.instance().enableLogCollection(
            !(getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.disable_every_log)));
```

Exception:

```
03-07 17:35:41.400: D/AndroidRuntime(8217): Shutting down VM
03-07 17:35:41.400: W/dalvikvm(8217): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417e4da0)
03-07 17:35:41.400: E/AndroidRuntime(8217): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-07 17:35:41.400: E/AndroidRuntime(8217): Process: org.linphone, PID: 8217
03-07 17:35:41.400: E/AndroidRuntime(8217): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service org.linphone.LinphoneService: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-07 17:35:41.400: E/AndroidRuntime(8217):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2824)
03-07 17:35:41.400: E/AndroidRuntime(8217):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:172)
03-07 17:35:41.400: E/AndroidRuntime(8217):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1390)
03-07 17:35:41.400: E/AndroidRuntime(8217):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-07 17:35:41.400: E/AndroidRuntime(8217):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
03-07 17:35:41.400: E/AndroidRuntime(8217):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
03-07 17:35:41.400: E/AndroidRuntime(8217):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-07 17:35:41.400: E/AndroidRuntime(8217):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-07 17:35:41.400: E/AndroidRuntime(8217):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
03-07 17:35:41.400: E/AndroidRuntime(8217):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
03-07 17:35:41.400: E/AndroidRuntime(8217):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-07 17:35:41.400: E/AndroidRuntime(8217): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-07 17:35:41.400: E/AndroidRuntime(8217):     at org.linphone.LinphoneService.onCreate(LinphoneService.java:140)
03-07 17:35:41.400: E/AndroidRuntime(8217):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2814)
03-07 17:35:41.400: E/AndroidRuntime(8217):     ... 10 more
```

Comment: Try downloading the source and investigating the line with the error

Comment: I think it has something to do with the get resources().getBoolean(). Or that call to instance(). Try adding some logging statements to see which one is null

Comment: @TameHog, Where I add some logging statements?

Comment: Right before those two lines add: `Log.d("LIN", "instance: " + LinphoneCoreFactory.instance());` and `Log.d("LIN", "resources: " + getResources() + " bool: " + getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.disable_every_log));`

Comment: It will say null for any elements that are null

Comment: LinphoneCoreFactory.instance() returns null

Comment: So that means you somehow need to create a new instance of it and set it that variable

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, to fix this your libs folder must be located inside app/src/main. Also if you are working with Android Studio, your libs folder must be called jniLibs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you provide me more details as I am getting this error with android studio.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean. I'm not longer working with that, but as far as I remember, all you have to do is place your linphone libs files in the folders that I mention.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
public static final synchronized LinphoneCoreFactory instance() {

    try {

        if (theLinphoneCoreFactory == null) {

            Class lFactoryClass = Class.forName(factoryName);

            theLinphoneCoreFactory = (LinphoneCoreFactory) lFactoryClass.newInstance();

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.err.println("Cannot instanciate factory ["+factoryName+"]");

    }

    return theLinphoneCoreFactory;

}
```

To:

```
public static final synchronized LinphoneCoreFactory instance() {

    try {

        if (theLinphoneCoreFactory == null) {

            theLinphoneCoreFactory = new LinphoneCoreFactoryImpl();

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.err.println("Cannot instanciate factory ["+factoryName+"]");

    }

    return theLinphoneCoreFactory;

}
```

Use: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650472/how-do-i-import-a-native-library-so-file-into-eclipse) to import native libraries. Copy all of the directory's and files from [this file](https://www.linphone.org/releases/android/liblinphone-android-sdk-2.3.2.zip) into the project's /libs/

Comment: It gives this error:  at org.linphone.LinphoneService.onCreate(LinphoneService.java:141)
03-07 18:17:58.788: E/AndroidRuntime(17765):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2814)
03-07 18:17:58.788: E/AndroidRuntime(17765):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:172)
03-07 18:17:58.788: E/AndroidRuntime(17765):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1390)
03-07 18:17:58.788: E/AndroidRuntime(17765):

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: 03-07 18:17:58.788: E/AndroidRuntime(17765): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load linphone-armeabi-v7a from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/org.linphone-6.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/org.linphone-6]: findLibrary returned null

Comment: That's me and the shared library isn't there. Did you include the natives?

Comment: I added all the libraries, which one is missing?

Comment: Updated answer check it out