# How to import .so file into eclipse c project

Tags: c, linux, eclipse, .so

I'm working on a C project using Eclipse IDE on my linux mint distro. I need to use some functions specified inside a .so file, but I don't know how to import this .so file into my project: how can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need an accompanying .h file. This works exactly like any other library you would use to program against, so you would normally need a lib*-dev package.

Comment: Does this help you:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650472/how-do-i-import-a-native-library-so-file-into-eclipse?