# loading library (.so file) in android

Tags: android, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating a product SDK: How do I add a native lib (.SO) and a jar with the SDK I am creating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882167/creating-a-product-sdk-how-do-i-add-a-native-lib-so-and-a-jar-with-the-sdk-i)

I'm trying to use com.android.SystemClock in an app, which calls a native method. I need to load the library that this native method belongs to (i.e. System.loadLibrary(...)). The method is defined in the file: frameworks/base/core/jni/android_os_SystemClock.cpp. How do I figure out which library this belongs to and load it as well?

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the make files and find out what libs it builds. Look for `LOCAL_MODULE`. That said, it is probably in `libandroid_runtime.so`.

And then again, if it is not part of the public SDK, you shouldn't be using it. It may change, break, not work on some devices, etc.

Comment: thanks. How do I load this .so file? System.loadLibrary("libandroid_runtime") throws an UnsatisfiedLinkError.

Comment: On Linux, the 'lib' is a prefix, not a part of the library name. Try `loadLibrary("android_runtime")`.